# Can I draw shapes and align them as a matrix or a table using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, shapes

Is there any way to create this final figure along with its text which depicts the idea behind k-fold cross-validation in statistics with shapes aligned like in a table or a matrix using TikZ? From where can I start, is there any similar code that can be of help? also is there any pre-defined shapes library to allow using more different shapes than what provided in the figure below?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but should be enough to get you started.

The idea is to define a macro for each of the shapes, with an argument for specifying the color. In TikZ, one can define `\mycirc`, `\myrect`, and `\mystar` for the three shapes as follows.

```
\tikzset{myshade/.style={minimum size=.4cm,shading=radial,inner color=white,outer color={#1!90!gray}}}
\newcommand\mycirc[1][]{\tikz\node[circle,myshade=#1]{};}
\newcommand\myrect[1][]{\tikz\node[rectangle,myshade=#1]{};}
\newcommand\mystar[1][]{\tikz\node[star,star points=15,star point height=2pt,myshade=#1]{};}
```

Then you can use these shapes in a `tabular` environment to produce a figure similar to the one posted.

## Full Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{myshade/.style={minimum size=.4cm,shading=radial,inner color=white,outer color={#1!90!gray}}}
\newcommand\mycirc[1][]{\tikz\node[circle,myshade=#1]{};}
\newcommand\myrect[1][]{\tikz\node[rectangle,myshade=#1]{};}
\newcommand\mystar[1][]{\tikz\node[star,star points=15,star point height=2pt,myshade=#1]{};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rccccc|ccc}
  Original Data & \mycirc[orange] & \mystar[pink] & \myrect[orange] & \mycirc[red] & \myrect[green] \\[.5cm]
  & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textit{Build Model With}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Predict On}} \\
  CV Group \#1 & \mycirc[orange] & \mystar[pink] & \myrect[orange] & \mycirc[red] &                & \mycirc[orange] & \mystar[pink] \\
  CV Group \#1 &                 & \mystar[pink] & \myrect[orange] & \mycirc[red] & \myrect[green] & \mycirc[orange] & \mystar[pink] 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without `tikz`.  This is composed of a series of stacks.  The symbols are just scaled bullets and rules, each put into a 2.6ex-width box, so that things align up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\SQ{\makebox[2.6ex]{\rule[-.4ex]{0ex}{2ex}\rule{1.8ex}{1.8ex}}}
\def\BL{\makebox[2.6ex]{}}
\def\OC{\makebox[2.6ex]{\scalerel*{\color{orange}\bullet}{\SQ}}}
\def\RC{\makebox[2.6ex]{\scalerel*{\color{red}\bullet}{\SQ}}}
\def\BC{\makebox[2.6ex]{\scalerel*{\color{blue}\bullet}{\SQ}}}
\def\GC{\makebox[2.6ex]{\scalerel*{\color{green}\bullet}{\SQ}}}
\def\OS{\color{orange}\SQ}
\def\RS{\color{red}\SQ}
\def\BS{\color{blue}\SQ}
\def\GS{\color{green}\SQ}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\Longstack[l]{
Original Data\\
\\
\\
CV Group \#1\\
CV Group \#2\\
CV Group \#3
}~
\Longstack{
\OC\RC\OS\RC\GS\GC\BC\RS\BS\GC\BC\OC\\
\\
Build Model With\\
\BL\BL\BL\BL\GS\GC\BC\RS\BS\GC\BC\OC\\
\OC\RC\OS\RC\BL\BL\BL\BL\BS\GC\BC\OC\\
\OC\RC\OS\RC\GS\GC\BC\RS\BL\BL\BL\BL
}~
\rule[-1ex]{2pt}{4.5\baselineskip}~
\Longstack[l]{
Predict On\\
\OC\RC\OS\RC\\
\GS\GC\BC\RS\\
\BS\GC\BC\OC
}
\end{document}
```

[image]